# how to include ngAnimate dependency in angular with yeoman

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, bower

I am create an angular application using the combination of yeoman, gruntjs and bower. I installed my angular app with `yo angular myapp` and then added few dependencies with bower and finally I would run `grunt server` and start working.

Only when I try to add the `ng-animate` dependency, I get into problems. This dependency gets downloaded but its scripting tag does not get added into `index.html` and the required reference does not get added into the `karma.conf.js` file.

I have tried to add these two references manually:

in the `index.html`

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

and in `karma/conf.js`

```
files: [
  ...
  'app/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
  ...
],
```

But this only works if the `grunt server` is already running. if I stop the server and re-run it again, the two reference that I have added manually vanish. How do I fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try one of the two following solutions:

1. add it to you bower.json file as a dependency, then run `bower update`

or

2. open terminal in you project directory and run: `bower install angular-animate`

either one will persist it to your bower.json file and cause it to not be deleted when you run grunt server again.

Answer (score 14):

## You have to do this:

**1. Install with bower:**

```
bower install angular-animate
```

**2. Add a *< script />* to your index.html:**

```
< script src="/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script >
```

**3. And add ngAnimate as a dependency for your app:**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);
```

See the ng-newsletter [post on ngAnimate](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/angular-animation.html) for more information on these steps