# Can't load ngAnimate in ng-boilerplate

Tags: angularjs, loading-animation

I'm using ng-boilerplate (v0.3.2-release), and I'm trying to add `ngAnimate` but it doesn't work! I'm missing something silly I'm sure.

I have a link to the correct CDN:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
```

Checking in the brower Sources shows the file is loaded correctly.

But when I try to add to my module ngAnimate:

```
angular.module( 'ngBoilerplate.UserDetails', [    
'ui.router',
'plusOne',
'ngAnimate'  
])
```

Grunt fails and says that `karma:unit:run` failed.

[image]

I've used bower to install ng-animate in the vendor dir ([like in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789977/how-to-include-nganimate-dependency-in-angular-with-yeoman)), but that didn't worked either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Added on behalf of OP.*

In the file build.config.js I'v added to vendor_files the path to ng-animate.js, problem solved :)